# c++ do socket close himself runtime

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, http, networking

I tried to find an answer to this question using google, but with no result.
Here is: for example, I have an HTTP server, that handles requests from the browser, parses HTTP headers and etc. If the client closes the connection, is my raw socket remains opened?

```
struct sockaddr_storage remoteaddr;
int client_sock = accept(sock_des, (sockaddr*)&remoteaddr, (socklen_t*)sizeof(remoteaddr));
std::thread* handler = new std::thread(handle_connection, client_sock, handler);
handler->join();

static void* handle_connection(int csock, std::thread& th_handler)
{
    // foo
    close(csock);
    //th_handler->
}
```

If no, does it make sense was it declared by a pointer in "heap" or not?
P.S. By the way: Is my code safe? :)

Comment: 1) don't use `new` with `std::thread` like this; 2) `join`'ing a thread waits for the thread to terminate, which defeats the purpose of using a thread at all. You may as well just call `handle_connection()` directly instead; 3) you can't pass `handler` to the `std::thread` constructor like this, nor does it make sense to try; 4) the thread closes the client socket when done using it, provided the thread does not terminate without calling `close()`, such as by a premature `return` or an uncaught exception. Consider using an RAII wrapper to ensure the socket is always closed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Sorry, i just forgot to say: I would like to make something like a session between server and browser. I mean using "while(true)" loop. So if my "close" function just not reached, do my socket closes himself? (removed from memory)

Comment: A socket is not closed and removed from memory until `close()` is called on it, or the owning process exits. Your thread can have a `while` loop, but it needs to break the loop eventually, such as when the client closes its end of the connection, or a socket error occurs. Either way, you must `close()` the socket that `accept()` returns.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In addition, what do you mean under 1) and 3)?  How should i "new" a thread and passing a handler?

Comment: `std::thread handler(handle_connection, client_sock); handler.detach(); ... static void* handle_connection(int csock) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

If a remote host closes a socket, the tcp connection will be closed, but the socket that the server has is a resource that remains allocated. You need to call `close(soc)` yourself to free up this resource. Sockets do not close themselves.